# Unix shell code. How to count the number of letters on each line from a text file

Tags: linux, shell, count

I have the following code in Linux shell file:
I need to replace the "..." with the number of letters of the coresponding line.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Filename is: $1\n"
nr_lines=$(wc -l <$1)
echo "Number of lines in files is: $nr_lines\n"

for line in $(seq 1 $nr_lines);
do
    echo "Line $line has  ... letters"


done
```

Comment: The parameter expansion `${#foo}` returns the length of `$foo`. Now figure out how to read a file a line at a time into a variable.

Comment: This comment above is by far the answer you need.

Comment: The pseudo code `get number of lines in file; for (i = 0; i < line count; i++)` is an anti-pattern in any language.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for iterating over all lines of a file is something like:

```
i=0; while read line; do
    printf "Line $((++i)) has %d letters\n" \
      "$(echo "$line" | tr -dc a-zA-Z | wc -c)";
done < input
```

but using `while read ...; do ... done < input` in a shell is often better done with awk:

```
awk '{gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); printf "Line %d has %d letters\n", NR, length}' input
```